# Can published papers from non-international journals decrease the level of a CV?

Tags: publications, peer-review, journals, cv, international

Consider a PhD candidate that still does not have publications in international journals but has some papers in local journals (peer reviewed but non-listed in international rankings) from their country. When looking for a job in academia or research institutes from prestigious universities, should these papers be mentioned on the CV?

I've heard people mentioning the these could decrease the value of the CV and in this case it is not "better than nothing". They argue that academia job market is used to "empty CV" as the publication process can take some time and these kinds of papers can suggest some poor research has been done.

Comment: This discussion takes place here: https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/71672/should-i-include-a-paper-with-a-low-impact-factor-in-my-cv